# What additional features do you get after spending five dollars on Steam?

Tags: steam

Spending more than $5 on Steam upgrades your account from a limited one to a premium one.  I know there are a few benefits and privileges enjoyed by premium account holders, such as adding friends.

What other features do you gain access to as a paid member that limited members don't get?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

According to [Steam's help page](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3330-IAGK-7663):

> Limited users are prevented from accessing several features on Steam,
>   including but not limited to:
>
> - Sending friend and group invites
> - Requesting access to groups
> - Opening group chat
> - Voting on Steam Reviews and Workshop items
> - Participating in the Steam Market
> - Trading Steam Community items (trading cards, booster packs, gems, etc.)
> - Posting frequently in the Steam Discussions
> - Gaining Steam Profile Levels (Locked to level 0) and Trading Cards
> - Submitting content on the Steam Workshop
> - Posting in an item's Steam Workshop Discussions
> - Accessing the Steam Web API
> - Using browser and mobile chat
> - Adding public artwork and screenshots
> - Adding messages to trade offers
> - Creating Steam groups
> - Counting towards Steam group membership

So, I assume you are able to do the above after spending five dollars.

Comment: Amazing, your posting times are the same...

Comment: Now we need to manage to give them the same net vote count.

Comment: Some of these features require more than just spending 5 dollars, though (not sure if that's relevant to the OP.)  For example, selling cards on the market requires that you set up two-factor authentication with the Steam Guard app, (apparently) in addition to spending $5.

Comment: @Steve-O Not true.  I've sold cards on the market, and I have never set up 2-factor.  The sale is just held for 15 days.

Comment: @JerryB Really?  It literally wouldn't let me do it without adding Steam Guard.  It specifically said I needed to add Steam Guard to participate in the market, and then for the first week anything I put up was "on hold" for a number of days before the sale would go through, just to make sure no one was hacking my account and selling stuff.  To this day I need to use Steam Guard to confirm all items put up for sale before they actually go up for sale.  Maybe it's a country-by-country thing then?

Comment: If I go to steamcommunity.com/market/ and click a link "Read about security requirements", a window pops up.  It makes it clear that I *can* trade or sell stuff, but the action is on hold for up to 15 days, to have time to cancel if it's not me.  Adding a Mobile Authenticator removes the hold, since you have to authenticate.  Last time I sold anything was back in Feb. this year, but everything I'm seeing says I still can.  Don't know why it forced you to.

Comment: @Steve-O Perhaps it forced you to because you'd previously linked your phone to your account for other purposes. That or you misinterpreted their insistent suggestions as requirement and didn't read _all_ the text.

Answer (score 263):

According to [this article by Valve](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3330-IAGK-7663), this is what a "premium" account gets over a "free" (officially called "limited account") one:

> - Sending friend and group invites
> - Requesting access to groups
> - Opening group chat
> - Voting on Steam Reviews and Workshop items
> - Participating in the Steam Market
> - Trading Steam Community items (trading cards, booster packs, gems, etc.)
> - Posting frequently in the Steam Discussions
> - Gaining Steam Profile Levels (Locked to level 0) and Trading Cards
> - Submitting content on the Steam Workshop
> - Posting in an item's Steam Workshop Discussions
> - Accessing the Steam Web API
> - Using browser and mobile chat
> - Adding public artwork and screenshots
> - Adding messages to trade offers
> - Creating Steam groups
> - Counting towards Steam group membership

Comment: To editor: you can accept friend requests with a limited account.

Comment: You can access the Steam API on a free account.

Comment: @Burgi you can't get an api key, though.