# Does buying a TF2 key unlock the community market?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, steam-community-market

I need access to the community market in order to sell some trading cards, does buying a TF2 key from the TF2 store unlock the community market?

Comment: I think the answers to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318491/what-additional-features-do-you-get-after-spending-five-dollars-on-steam) will answer this one.  I believe you just have to spend 5 dollars to unlock access to the community market.  I would imagine the type of item you purchase doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

If the value of the key is less than $5 USD, **no, it will not**. That is the amount one needs to spend in order to remove the 'limited' status from one's steam account, as laid out by Timmy Jim in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/318491/what-additional-features-do-you-get-after-spending-five-dollars-on-steam).